# Как правильно получить данные от клиента?

Tags: c#, .net

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не знаю, как получить ответ от клиента на сервере.
Взял с MSDN пример асинхронного сокет сервера.
собственно сервер:

```
public class StateObject
{
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
    private static String response = String.Empty;
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public AsynchronousSocketListener()
    {

    }
    public static void StartListening()
    {
        int countSockets = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        Console.WriteLine(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Any;
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 5300);
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);
            while (true)
            {
                allDone.Reset();
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...(" + (countSockets + 1) + ")");
                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);
                allDone.WaitOne();
                countSockets++;
            }
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        allDone.Set();
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);   
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
            {
                int[] numbersArray = Program.arrayGenerate(300); 
                /* Посылаем сериализованный массив */
                Send(handler, string.Join(",", numbersArray));
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                    content.Length, content);

            }
            else
            {
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }
    public static byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);
            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

И клиент:

```
public class AsynchronousClient
{
    private const int port = 5300;
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private static String response = String.Empty;

    public static void StartClient()
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("asus");
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            Send(client, "Client From ip: " + ipAddress  + " connected<EOF>");
            sendDone.WaitOne();
            Receive(client);
            receiveDone.WaitOne();
            // Write the response to the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Received array : ");
            int[] array = Program.toIntArray(response, ',');
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine(i + "| " + array[i]);
}
            int[] arraySort = new int[array.Length];
            Array.Sort(array);
            /* Отдаю обратно массив */
            Send(client, string.Join(",", arraySort));
            sendDone.WaitOne();
            // Release the socket.
            Console.ReadLine();
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            client.EndConnect(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            connectDone.Set();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                }
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Я пробовал реализовать на сервере методы Receive и ReceiveCallback как на клиенте но цепляя их к handler я получал exception, т.к. AcceptCallback вызывает BeginReceive(.. ReadCellback), а уже в нем сокет закрывается. А если его не закрыть после отправки, то на клиенте не удается получить данные. В общем, замкнутый круг какой-то. Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему?